# Why randomness space must be significantly larger than the commitment space |R|>>|C| in order to generate a commitment string?

Tags: collision-resistance, randomness, commitments

[image]

Why randomness space must be significantly larger than the commitment space |R|>|C|? the picture is from https://youtu.be/IkNZWJFcfcU?t=236

Answer (score 1):

For the hiding property we require that the commitment value provides no information about the message. In particular we hope that for any given message $m$ it is possible for $H(m,r)$ to take all possible values in $C$ (otherwise one could exclude some messages as corresponding to some commitments). If $H$ behaves like a random function, then it unlikely to have this surjective property unless [$|R|>|C|\log|C|$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

More powerfully we probably want the values of $H(m,r)$ for any fixed $m$ to be distributed uniformly across the values of $C$.

Note that these are information theoretic "zero knowledge" requirements rather than complexity/computation bounded requirements.

Comment: For any secret value the random blinding of a Pedersen commitment covers the whole image space uniformly. It can do this because the random blinding is a random permutation rather than a random function.

Comment: "In particular we hope that for any given message $m$ it is possible for $H(m,r)$ to take all possible values in $C$"; while this would be sufficient, this is not actually necessary.  What is necessary is that any plausible adversary be unable to obtain any information about $m$ from the commitment; however, because computationally unbounded adversaries are not plausible, we can consider lesser goals (such as deducing information about $m$ computationally infeasible..)

Comment: @poncho: There are three levels of hiding in commitment schemes [perfect, statistical, and computational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commitment_scheme#Perfect,_statistical,_and_computational_hiding). The lecturer is tacitly requiring statistical hiding (hence my reference to information theory) and the requirement $|R|\gg |C|$ is necessary to meet this.